# Match Function Excel 2013 - Formula will not calculate

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

I am using a tutorial to create a KPI gauge  on a dashboard. I have listed my Raw Data and that to use for the dashboard, as shown on the tutorial. When I type =MATCH( and click the cell it does not remain in the formula when I move to my raw data. It highlights cell B3 as usual, but when I move to my other worksheet the formula then deletes B3 and changes.

[this is the error that is shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6bAOX.jpg)

[what I am typing to start the formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GdovH.jpg)

[this is what it changes to when I go to my data sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GCkLs.jpg)

Comment: type a comma after B3 before moving to the other sheet

Comment: no worries i have posted as an answer for others if they have similar issue, please accept as correct

Comment: How do I accept?

Comment: there should be a tick you can click near the answer, it may make you wait around 10 mins to accept tho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are using a comma after you type or select cell B3, to move to the next part of the formula, i.e the look up range

Example:

```
=MATCH(B3,Sheet1!A1:A19,0)
```

Comment: Is there a reason why the Index will now not work? Again, I am copying from https://www.youtube.com/user/excel365hu - I use =INDEX(C10:C11), MERCH.!Q7:Z10) - where C10:C11 are the cells using MATCH and Q7:Z10 are the cells on the other worksheet I want to use for the value.

Comment: you need something like this: = INDEX(DATA ARRAY, MATCH( B3, MATCH ARRAY, 0), 1 )

Comment: my best advise would be keep at it, INDEX & MATCH is one of the most use formulas you can master